# Modify element based on subelement's partial value via xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the follow XML 1.0 code

```
<oldEle userlabel="label1">
    <ele1>%02d.jpeg</ele1>
</oldEle>

<oldEle userlabel="label2">
    <ele1>%02d.tiff</ele1>
</oldEle>
```

I want to change the oldEle to jpeg and tiff for each oldEle using xsl v1.0. Essentially I want xsl to do this:

```
<JPEG userlabel="label1">
    <ele1>%02d.jpeg</ele1>
</JPEG>

<TIFF userlabel="label2">
    <ele1>%02d.tiff</ele1>
</TIFF>
```

I have tried the following but it is not working:

```
<xsl:template match="/oldEle">
    <xsl:for-each select="/oldEle">
    <xsl:if test="contains(/oldEle/ele1,'jpeg')">
        <JPEG>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </JPEG>      
    </xsl:if>      
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarentee the **ele1** element will only ever contain one full-stop, you could extract the file extension using the xpath function **substring-after**, and then use the **xsl:element** function to create a new element with that name

```
<xsl:element name="{substring-after(ele1, '.')}">
```

There would however be extra complexity needed because you need to convert it to upper case too, and in XSLT1.0 this would be achieved by the means of the cumbersome **translate** function

```
<xsl:element 
   name="{translate(
     substring-after(ele1, '.'), 
     'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 
     'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')}">
```

One other thing to note is you are matching on `/oldEle` which imply that **oldEle** is the root element of your XML. As you can only ever have one root element in well-formed XML this is probably not what you want.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="oldEle[contains(ele1, '.')]">
      <xsl:element name="{translate(substring-after(ele1, '.'), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML

```
<root>
   <oldEle userlabel="label1">
      <ele1>%02d.jpeg</ele1>
   </oldEle>
   <oldEle userlabel="label2">
      <ele1>%02d.tiff</ele1>
   </oldEle>
</root>
```

The following is output

```
<root>
   <JPEG userlabel="label1">
      <ele1>%02d.jpeg</ele1>
   </JPEG>
   <TIFF userlabel="label2">
      <ele1>%02d.tiff</ele1>
   </TIFF>
</root>
```

The XSLT would fail though if **ele1** contained more than one full stop though. For example, consider the following XML

```
<root>
   <oldEle userlabel="label1">
      <ele1>test.image1.jpeg</ele1>
   </oldEle>
   <oldEle userlabel="label2">
      <ele1>test.image2.tiff</ele1>
   </oldEle>
</root>
```

In this case, in XSLT1.0, you would probably need a recursived named template to extract the file extenstion.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="oldEle[contains(ele1, '.')]">
      <xsl:variable name="extension">
         <xsl:call-template name="getExtension">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="ele1"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:element name="{translate($extension, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="getExtension">
      <xsl:param name="text"/>
      <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'.'"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <xsl:call-template name="getExtension">
               <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This would also generate the same output.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it in my program but it still didn't work. I got all of the values printed out when I tried in a browser. The xsl file is exactly what you have mentioned above. The xsl file is:                                                                          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
      <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xslFile.xsl"?>
      <root>
        <oldEle userlabel="label1">
          <ele1>%02d.jpeg</ele1>
        </oldEle>
        <oldEle userlabel="label2">
          <ele1>%02d.tiff</ele1>
        </oldEle>
      </root>

Comment: If you are outputting results in the browser using the `xml-stylesheet` directive, then you probably want to be displaying the result as HTML, not XML.

Comment: I got further but now it keeps giving me the same ext e.g. if jpeg was first, all oldEle would be JPEG... I tried this for each type of image type but still only get the first type for all oldEle. <xsl:template match="oldEle[contains(ele1, '.jpeg')]"> <xsl:element name ="JPEG"> <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> </xsl:element> </xsl:template> thank you, sorry I am new to xslt.

Comment: I think I know why it is always using only the first ext e.g. jpeg. {translate(substring-after(//sig:outputFileFormat, '.'),
                   'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')} the substring-after is trying to rematch from the beginning so it always finds the first ext....

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a *non-recursive* and more efficient XSLT 1.0 solution that works successfully with any number of image format extensions, assuming they are statically known**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:suffixes>
  <s>jpeg</s><s>JPEG</s>
  <s>tiff</s><s>TIFF</s>
  <s>giv</s><s>GIV</s>
  <s>png</s><s>PNG</s>
 </my:suffixes>

 <xsl:variable name="vSufs" select="document('')/*/my:suffixes/s"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:variable name="vSufFound" select=
    "$vSufs[position() mod 2 = 1]
         [substring(translate(current()/ele1, ., ''),
                    string-length(translate(current()/ele1, ., ''))
                    )
         =
          '.'
         ]"/>
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="not($vSufFound)">
      <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:element name="{$vSufFound/following-sibling::s[1]}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
       </xsl:element>
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<t>
    <oldEle userlabel="label1">
        <ele1>%02d.jpeg</ele1>
    </oldEle>
    <oldEle userlabel="label2">
        <ele1>%02d.tiff</ele1>
    </oldEle>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<t>
   <JPEG userlabel="label1">
      <ele1>%02d.jpeg</ele1>
   </JPEG>
   <TIFF userlabel="label2">
      <ele1>%02d.tiff</ele1>
   </TIFF>
</t>
```

**When applied on the following XML document (where more than one dot characters are present in the string value of `ele`**:

```
<root>
    <oldEle userlabel="label1">
        <ele1>test.image1.jpeg</ele1>
    </oldEle>
    <oldEle userlabel="label2">
        <ele1>test.image2.tiff</ele1>
    </oldEle>
</root>
```

**again correct result is produced:**

```
<root>
   <JPEG userlabel="label1">
      <ele1>test.image1.jpeg</ele1>
   </JPEG>
   <TIFF userlabel="label2">
      <ele1>test.image2.tiff</ele1>
   </TIFF>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

In this transformation we are using the following XPath 1.0 expression to implement the standard XPath 2.0 `ends-with($t, $suf)` function:

```
$suf = substring($t, string-length($t) - string-length($suf) +1)
```

Comment: This is great. But I still can't get the easier version working. It keeps giving me the same ext e.g. if jpeg was first, all oldEle would be JPEG... I tried this for each type of image type but still only get the first type for all oldEle.                                                                  <xsl:template match="oldEle[contains(ele1, '.jpeg')]">
    <xsl:element name ="JPEG">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry I am new to xslt.

Comment: @Evan: You need simply copy and paste the XSLT code and the source XML in their respective files, then run the transformation and you should get exactly the same result (the wanted one) that I am getting. If you use different code -- then nobody can guarantee in advance what this different code would produce. Please, just run the transformation on the two XML documents from my answer and verify you are getting exactly the results that I reported. If this is negative, then either you had a copy/paste error or (less likely), you are using a buggy XSLT processor.

Comment: Thank you Dimitre for your help. I pasted and it doens't work not to my surprise. I am using a custom xlt and xml schema. It seems to me that Tim's suggestion would have worked. Here is what I have now

Comment: <xsl:template match="//root:Config/root:ImageSink[contains(//root:Config/sig:ImageSink/root:outputFileFormat, '.')]">
    <xsl:element name="{translate(substring-after(//root:Config/root:ImageSink/root:outputFileFormat, '.'),
                   'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: To me this is a very straight forward approach to what I am trying to do. Thank you for your expert help!

Comment: @Evan: Please, edit this question or ask a new question (recommended) with the new information/problem you have. The comments do not provide a good format for code. This answers solves your current question completely and I will be glad to help with your future questiond.

Comment: Thank you Dimitre! I appreciate your help and professional advice. I've started a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903013/make-new-node-using-sub-node-sub-string

Comment: @Evan: I see that you got a good answer from TimC to your new question. It is time to *accept* (by clicking the check-mark next to the answer) one of the answers to *this* question.